# Bash batch image resizer

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I have an image resizer(bottom). Now I want to use it to batch resize pngs. Problem is to run it only once for each file. This snippet creates new images over the created ones:

```
for image in find . -type f -name "*.png"; do
   /Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "$image" 200 133
done
```

Resizer:

```
#!/bin/bash

###### LOCAL VARIABLES
convert=/usr/bin/convert
identify=/usr/bin/identify
image=$1
heigth=$2
width=$3
usage_message="Usage: imre image heigth width"
usage_example="Example: imre anyImage.png 50 50"
space=""

###### ACTIONS
clear
echo $space
echo "*** START image resizer script ***"
echo $space

if [ -z "$image" ] || [ -z "$heigth" ] || [ -z "$width" ] ; 
    then
    echo $usage_message
    echo $space
    echo $usage_example
    echo $space
    echo "*** END image resizer script ***" 
    echo $space ; exit 1
fi

echo "To modify $image to $heigth x $width (HxW)"
echo "Given image data: "
identify $image
convert $image -resize "${heigth}"x"${width}" $image
echo "$1"

echo $space
echo "*** END image resizer script ***" 
echo $space
exit 0
```

Comment: `convert "$image" -resize ...` - missing `$`. Also best if you will _always_ quote variables. here are some cases when it isn't needed but in general it is much better...

Comment: Thanks for comment. Sorry I was editing it. The imre does run. But the first snippet runs in circles. Has to do it only once.

Comment: I am using @setempler first solution. Works like charm. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop expands not to the expected, because `find` is not called.

Instead, every single word of the `find` command (including the arguments) is used as argument for the `for` loop.

A **solution** is to use `find` in a **sub-shell**, as in

```
for image in `find . -type f -name "*.png"`; do
   /Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "$image" 200 133
done
```

or

```
for image in $(find . -type f -name "*.png"); do
   /Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "$image" 200 133
done
```

You can easily **check** it with an `echo`:

```
for image in `find . -type f -name "*.png"`; do
   echo "/Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh \"$image\" 200 133"
done
```

For your example, the result of the check:

```
for image in find . -type f -name "*.png"; do
   echo "/Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh \"$image\" 200 133"
done
```

yields:

```
/Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "find" 200 133
/Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "." 200 133
/Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "-type" 200 133
/Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "f" 200 133
/Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "-name" 200 133
/Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "*.png" 200 133
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify for others to read. This is the full batcher working. Uses imre resizer:

```
#!/bin/bash

###### LOCAL VARIABLES
heigth=$1
width=$2
usage_message="Usage: batch_imre heigth width"
usage_example="Example: batch_imre 50 50"
space=""

clear
echo $space
echo "*** START batch image resizer script ***"
echo $space

if [ -z "$heigth" ] || [ -z "$width" ] ; 
    then
    echo $usage_message
    echo $space
    echo $usage_example
    echo $space
    echo "*** END batch image resizer script ***" 
    echo $space ; exit 1
fi

for image in `find . -type f -name "*.png"`; do
    /Users/dev/scripts/./imre.sh "$image" $heigth $width
done

echo $space
echo "*** END batch image resizer script ***" 
echo $space
exit 0
```